# Java Collections.sort() Comparator

Tags: java, sorting

I am sorting my custom objects. Custom object contain state and timestamp. First I have to sort against state then timestamp. State having below values

> Running, Waiting, Registering, Completed and Aborted

So state having value Running should come on top then Waiting and so on.

If I have to sort alphabetically then I can do easily via

```
state1.compareTo(state2)
```

But can I sort with this criteria. Please help me to write this logic.

**EDIT**

As you people suggested I took Enum

```
private enum TournamentState {
    Running,
    Waiting,
    Registering,
    Completed,
    Aborted
}
```

And compare like below

```
int sort = EnumState.valueOf(status1).compareTo(EnumState.valueOf(status2));

if(sort != 0){
  return sort;
}else{
   return (int) (time1 - time2);
}
```

*Thank you very much for your support.*

Comment: just check if `state1.compareTo(state2)` returns 0, meaning both states are equal, and then either compare the timestamp for equal states or return the result of the state comparision for unequal states.

Comment: You already mention ``Comparator``, what does yours look like right now?

Comment: but what if state1.compareTo(state2) does not return 0

Comment: Then you just return that as I wrote: "or return the result of the state comparision for unequal states."

Comment: I think you might be facing problem ordering records based on state, means which should come first, second and so on. You can declare your state as an enum and try to give them ordinal according to your order and then use the ordinal instead of state name in the comparator.

Comment: @AmitYadav then the 2 objects have a different state and you are done comparing.

Comment: Put the states in an Enum, in the order you want them to be since Enum already implements Comparable. Sorts the objects by the states and then by the timestamps

Comment: i wouldn't rely on ordinal values, what if you add new states tomorrow without factoring in the comparison logic. Better would be to have integer rank as member of enum.

Answer (score 4):

You can use composition of comparator functions:

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getState)
    .thenComparing(MyClass::getTimeStamp);
```

The last line may need to be changed accordingly, depending on the data type:

```
.thenComparingLong(MyClass::getTimeStamp); //if it's a long TS
```

Or even

```
.thenComparing((ts1, ts2) -> {
    //custom comparison logic for time stamp values
    return result;
 });
```

`Comparator.thenComparing` is documented with this comment:

> Returns a lexicographic-order comparator with another comparator. If this Comparator considers two elements equal, i.e. compare(a, b) == 0, other is used to determine the order.

Note that `MyClass.state` is assumed to be comparable in this case, such as being an enum, which is inherently comparable. If it's plain strings, then you may need custom logic there too, such as with:

```
final String order = "Running, Waiting, Registering, Completed and Aborted";
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = 
  Comparator.comparingInt(e -> order.indexOf(e.getState()))
    .thenComparing(MyClass::getTimeStamp);
```

Comment: `Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getState)` will not sort according to the OP requirement if the enum values are not initially in this order. A custom comparator is required.

Comment: @davidxxx That's right, good catch. I've edited. But  it would be best if the `state` field is of an enum type.

Comment: No you are good : this field is an enum but on what I would stress on is the `thenComparing()` will sort according to the order of the declaration of the enum values that may not be the expected for this sort (not the case according to the OP update) but that may also change in the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom comparator for your `State` class, like this :

```
public final class StateComparator implements Comparator<State>
{

    private int getRank(final State s)
    {
        if (s.getValue().equals("Running"))
        {
            return 1;
        } else if (s.getValue().equals("Waiting")) {
            return 2;
        } else if (s.getValue().equals("Registering")) {
            return 3;
        } else if (s.getValue().equals("Completed")) {
            return 4;
        } else if s.getValue().equals("Aborted") {
            return 5;
        } else {
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

    }

    public int compare(final State s1, final State s3)
    {
        return getRank(s1) - getRank(S2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum like

```
public enum State {
    RUNNING, WAITING, REGISTERING, COMPLETED, ABORTED
}
```

By default, these states will get an ordinal integer which will be according to the order you write them in the enum. And then use this `State` as your `state` in your object and the create comparator

```
Comparator<MyClass> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getState)
    .thenComparing(MyClass::getTimeStamp);
```

And then you can use the comparator to sort your collections